# Set permissions for "all" to same permissions as owner

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have a very large base of files with varying permissions. I'd like to allow everyone with access to the server the same permissions as I have currently (since I created all of the files).

Is it possible to give the "other" or "all" group the same permissions as are currently set for the "owner" group?

Example:

```
drwxr-xr-x folder_1
-r-xr--r-- file_1.txt
```

Becomes:

```
drwxrwxrwx folder_1
-r-xr-xr-x file_1.txt
```

This would have to be recursive as it's going to affect many directories and files - can this be done through chmod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `all` to `user` by using the `a=u`:

```
chmod a=u file1 file2 file3 prefix*
```